# derivatives of function f: [0; + ∞)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

ok, this exercise is quite difficult, at least (for me).
f: [0; + ∞) → R satisfies
$$
f'(x) \left( f(x)+1 \right)^2 = \frac{1}{1+6x}
$$

for $x>0,  f(0)=2$ . So $f(x)$= ?

I'm really quite confused where to start. I tried to do something but it gave me 3√(1/2 ln(1+6x) +27 -1) but I don't think it's okay

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x):=\frac{1}{3}(f(x)+1)^3.$ Then we have

$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{1+6x},$$

Hence

$$g(x)= \frac{1}{6} \ln (1+6x)+c.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but then it would be f(x)= ( 3√ (1/6 ln(1+6x)) +2 ? can you correct me if i'm wrong? pls

Answer (score 0):

set $y=f(x)\to \frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)$
$$
f'(x) \left( y+1 \right)^2 = \frac{1}{1+6x}
$$
means
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left( y+1 \right)^2 =\frac{1}{1+6x}$$
and then
$$\left( y+1 \right)^2\,dy=\frac{dx}{1+6x}$$
now integrate both sides. Don't forget the constant of integration which can be found with the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you, I have integrated it in both parts as you say and it gives me 1/6 ln(1+6x)+C . but still, don't give me the same results that the options that they give me. All the options have 3^√ ahead, could it be(3^√ (1/6 ln(1+6x)) +2  ?

Comment: @mario the solution is $$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} (\log (6 x+1)+54)}-1$$

Comment: i dont have this opcion , only this 4 options : (3^√ (1/6 ln(1+6x)+27) -1 ,(3^√ (1/6 ln(1+6x)) +2 , (3^√ (1/2 ln(1+6x)) +2 ,  (3^√ (1/2 ln(1+6x)+27) -1   . can the problem be wrong?

Comment: It is the 4th @mario 54/2 = 27